# Plotting two distributions in seaborn.jointplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two `pandas` dataframes I would like to plot in the same seaborn [jointplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html). It looks something like this (commands are don in an IPython shell; `ipython --pylab`):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = pd.read_csv('my_dataset.csv')
g = sns.jointplot('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', iris)
```

The keys in the two dataframes are identical.
How do I plot my values in the same plot (different color of course)? And even more detailed: How do I plot both dataset, but only having the distribution of the first on at the top and side? I.e. only plot the dots.

Comment: I doubt this is the best way, but you could use the `hue` option  of `pairplot` to get different colors (after first merging the datasets).  http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html

Comment: Btw, it is now recommended to use `%matplotlib inline` after starting ipython rather than invoking with `--pylab`

Comment: What is the difference between `--pylab` and `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: And for your first comment. I prefer the solution given by @jianxun-li.

Comment: The new Seaborn v0.11 release solves your problem elegantly via the hue parameter. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63843331/7952162

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by modifying the underlying data of `sns.JointGrid`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# simulate some artificial data
# ========================================
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1,0.5],[0.5,1]], size=200)
data2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1,-0.8],[-0.8,1]], size=100)

# both df1 and df2 have bivaraite normals, df1.size=200, df2.size=100
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['x1', 'y1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['x2', 'y2'])


# plot
# ========================================   
graph = sns.jointplot(x=df1.x1, y=df1.y1, color='r')

graph.x = df2.x2
graph.y = df2.y2
graph.plot_joint(plt.scatter, marker='x', c='b', s=50)
```

[image]

Comment: @DanielThaagaardAndreasen You are most welcome. Glad that it helped. :-)

Comment: How can you show the second distribution also in the histograms on the side?

Comment: @JianxunLi Any tips on a slick way to add a legend?

Comment: @user1834164 `graph.plot_marginals(plt.hist, c='b')`

Comment: @user1834164: Since the release of Seaborn v0.11, this is possible very easily. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63843331/7952162

Comment: @NimrodMorag - The code you proposed return the error `AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'vertical'`.  @ManuCJ - Thank you for the example pointing the new `hue` parameter, however, this is not as versatile as to plot together any two unrelated data set. I still would like another answer for @user1834164 question.

Comment: @Stefano sorry, here you go:
```graph.ax_marg_y.hist(df2.y2, color='b', orientation="horizontal");
graph.ax_marg_x.hist(df2.x2, color='b')```

Answer (score 5):

A better solution, in my opinion, is to use the axes handles for the joint and marginal distributions that `sns.joinplot` returns. Using those (the names are `ax_joint`, `ax_marg_x` and `ax_marg_y`) is also possible to draw on the marginal distributions plots.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data1 = np.random.randn(100)
data2 = np.random.randn(100)
data3 = np.random.randn(100)
data4 = np.random.randn(100)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': data1, 'col2':data2})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': data3, 'col2':data4})

axs = sns.jointplot('col1', 'col2', data=df1)
axs.ax_joint.scatter('col1', 'col2', data=df2, c='r', marker='x')

# drawing pdf instead of histograms on the marginal axes
axs.ax_marg_x.cla()
axs.ax_marg_y.cla()
sns.distplot(df1.col1, ax=axs.ax_marg_x)
sns.distplot(df1.col2, ax=axs.ax_marg_y, vertical=True)
```

[image: distplots on marginal axes]

Comment: I am able to reproduce your code, however, I would like to plot a new histogram in the vertical marginal axis (not a `sns.distplot` plot as in your example). I tried to use the function `sns.histplot` instead but the results end up rotated 90 degrees off. How can you add and new histogram at the vertical marginal axis?

Comment: @Stefano try adding the following 2 lines at the end of the snippet I provided in the answer:
`df_new = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.rand(100)})
sns.histplot(data=df_new, ax=axs.ax_marg_y, y="col1", stat="density")`

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier after drawing the jointplot, change to the axis on which you want to draw something and use then normal pyplot or axis based seaborn plots:

```
g=sns.jointplot(...)
plt.sca("axis_name")
plt.plot/plt.scatter/.../sns.kde(ax="axis_name")
```

The axis name is either `ax_joint` for the 2d-Plot or `ax_marg_x` or `ax_marg_y` for the 1d Plots on the side.

Furthermore, if you want to use the jointplot structure but plot all plots by pyplot, use the `cla` function, e.g. for clearing the 2d-Plot:

```
g.ax_joint.cla()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
```