# How to plot a jointplot with 'hue' parameter in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to have the plot of the following command line:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, hue= 'sex')
```

if the parameter 'hue' was implemented in jointplot.

How can I do this?

Maybe superposing two joint plots?

Comment: Did you check already [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31543774/5741205)? You may also want to check [this solution from seaborn's author](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/294)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This functionality was added in the  [v0.11](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-11-0-september-2020) Seaborn release in September 2020 (see e. g. the [release blog post](https://medium.com/@michaelwaskom/announcing-the-release-of-seaborn-0-11-3df0341af042) or the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html)).

The documentation now features a great example based on the penguins dataset:

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
```

[image: seaborn jointplot example with scatterplot]

I further would like to give a minimal example for a Kernel density estimation in the joint plot (a 2d [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)):

```
# optional: sns.set(style='darkgrid')
data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
        'y': [2, 4, 1.5, 4, 3, 5], 
        'class': ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0']}
sns.jointplot(data=data, x='x', y='y', hue='class', kind='kde',
              fill=True, joint_kws={'alpha': 0.7})
```

[image: seaborn jointplot example with kdeplot]

Comment: it's throwing an error, `unexpected keyword argument` first alpha remove it next fill remove it next hue and finally worked I truly don't know why can't use `kind` with `hue` (notice I'm using `reg` for kind)

Answer (score 13):

A simple alternative is to use `seaborn.lmplot` -- even if x and y histogram are not drawn.

```
sns.lmplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='sex', data=tips, fit_reg=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**You can't, unfortunately**

and it won't be implemented in the near future, because the simplicity of jointplot should be preserved.

See here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/365

You can only do it halfway (without the hist for both classes): [Plotting two distributions in seaborn.jointplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539815/plotting-two-distributions-in-seaborn-jointplot?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14343204)

Comment: Hm, so what does the link say if not "no" and "you won't be able to do it in the future" and "because the simplicity of jointplot should be preserved"?
My answer fully summarizes what the link says, the link itself is my source... So what would you want to change?

Comment: @echonax,the answer is here, you can't do it. The link just supports my statement. What should I change then?

Comment: It's interesting to see how @Mayou36 concludes this won't be implemented in the near future and then in less than a year, the feature is indeed implemented!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using pairplot.

```
g = sns.pairplot(data=tips[['total_bill','tip','sex']], hue='sex', corner=True, )
```

[image]