# AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'hue'

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to get to know seaborn functions. I was trying to execute the jointplot function as it appears on the seaborn website on JupyterLab 2.2.6

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot

the code is as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
```

trying this I get a blank plot on screen and an error message that reads:

```
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'hue'
```

how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a jointplot with 'hue' parameter in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419822/how-to-plot-a-jointplot-with-hue-parameter-in-seaborn)

Comment: What is the version of seaborn you use?

Comment: apparently i was using seaborn 0.10 and this feature was added in seaborn 0.11

Answer (score 4):

Just update **seaborn** in the terminal: `$ sudo pip install seaborn -U`

To check your version, run this python command:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.__version__
```

Comment: Seems that it doesn't work inside jupyter notebook, with `import sys` and updating it. You should indeed `$ workon` into your virenv and do the procedure there.