# Multiple seaborn joint distribution plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I wish to plot several [joint distribution scatter plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539815/plotting-two-distributions-in-seaborn-jointplot) on the same figure. I use the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1,0.5],[0.5,1]], size=200)
data2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1,-0.8],[-0.8,1]], size=100)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['x1', 'y1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['x2', 'y2'])


fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
graph1 = sns.jointplot(x=df1.x1, y=df1.y1, color='r', ax = axs[0])
graph2 = sns.jointplot(x=df1.x1, y=df1.y1, color='r', ax = axs[1])
graph3 = sns.jointplot(x=df1.x1, y=df1.y1, color='r', ax = axs[2])
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want 3 subplots and each one of the subplots contains a jointplot?

Comment: @DavidG: exactly