# Seaborn jointplot group colour coding (for both scatter and density plots)

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to use sns.jointplot to visualise the association between X and Y in the presence of two groups. However, in

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips)
```

[image]

there is no "hue" option as in other sns plots such as sns.scatterplot. How could one assign different colours for different groups (e.g. hue="smoker") in both the scatter plot, as well as the two overlapping density plots.

In R this could be done by creating a scatter plot with two marginal density plots as shown in [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/#scatter-plot-with-marginal-density-plots). [image]

What is the equivalent in sns? If this is not possible in sns, is there another python package that can be used for this?

Comment: Some relevant links

* https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/365,  
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210955/seaborn-jointplot-add-colors-for-each-class, 
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539815/plotting-two-distributions-in-seaborn-jointplot?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: thank you. I've seen the first and the last questions but the second didn't come up in my search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`jointplot` is a simple wrapper around `sns.JointGrid`. If you create a `JointGrid` object and add plots to it manually, you will have much more control over the individual plots.

In this case, your desired `jointplot` is simply a `scatterplot` combined with a `kdeplot`, and what you want to do is pass `hue='smoker'` (for example) to `scatterplot`.

The `kdeplot` is more complex; `seaborn` doesn't really support one KDE for each class, AFAIK, so I was forced to plot them individually (you could use a `for` loop with more classes).

Accordingly, you can do this:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
grid = sns.JointGrid(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips)

g = grid.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, hue='smoker', data=tips)
sns.kdeplot(tips.loc[tips['smoker']=='Yes', 'total_bill'], ax=g.ax_marg_x, legend=False)
sns.kdeplot(tips.loc[tips['smoker']=='No', 'total_bill'], ax=g.ax_marg_x, legend=False)
sns.kdeplot(tips.loc[tips['smoker']=='Yes', 'tip'], ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True, legend=False)
sns.kdeplot(tips.loc[tips['smoker']=='No', 'tip'], ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True, legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: At the time of this answer this may not have been possible in sns.jointplot, but in version 0.11.1 this is natively supported with the "hue" argument.
http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html

Comment: not with reg though: `ValueError: Use of 'hue' with 'kind='reg'' is not currently supported.`
I'm using 0.12.2