# Array length does not match index length pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a plot similar to the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839345/seaborn-jointplot-group-colour-coding-for-both-scatter-and-density-plots). I'm not sure why, but when I run the following code, I get an error:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(single_frag_cnv_sizes, single_frag_cn)), columns=['x','y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(multi_frag_cnv_sizes, multi_frag_cn)), columns=['x','y'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(total_cnv_sizes, total_cn)), columns=['x','y'])
df1['kind'] = 'single_frag'
df2['kind'] = 'multi_frag'
df3['kind'] = 'total'
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index = True)

grid = sbn.JointGrid(x='x', y='y', data=df)

g = grid.plot_joint(sbn.scatterplot, hue='kind', data=df)
```

produces the ValueError `array length 38210 does not match index length 38321`.

I've double checked that the arrays I'm creating dataframes for are the same length:

```
print(len(single_frag_cnv_sizes))
print(len(multi_frag_cnv_sizes))
print(len(total_cnv_sizes))
print(len(single_frag_cn))
print(len(multi_frag_cn))
print(len(total_cn))

13626
5122
19573
13626
5122
19573
```

Does anyone see an error?

Comment: Is it possible that you have nan values in the columns of the arrays?

Comment: Try printing df and look at head/tail. Is it what you expect?

Comment: In response to @FabricioFonseca's comment try `df.fillna(0)` and see if that fixes it