# plot multiple(2) seaborn jointplot in a single plot (Overlap one over another)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot 2 seaborn jointplot in a single plot from `pd.df`, to understand the dist b/ two classes and their corresponding features in a single graph.

Could some one help me to achieve this? I found solutions for kde plot from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899463/how-can-i-overlay-two-graphs-in-seaborn), but I am not sure, hw to get the plot for jointplot?

Below is the sample code & plot.
(X & y lim is same for both the plots)

```
sns.jointplot("x", "y", data=df[class = 1], kind="hex")
sns.jointplot("x", "y", data=df[class =0], kind="hex")
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot multiple Seaborn Jointplot in Subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042255/how-to-plot-multiple-seaborn-jointplot-in-subplot)

Comment: Which type of jointplot  are you using?  Could you add a simple demo that creates a similar jointplot?

Comment: I would like to overlap the graphs one over the another not as subplot @DavidG

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539815/plotting-two-distributions-in-seaborn-jointplot answer your questions?